# Need in-depth understanding of mysqli "bind_result()"

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm still confused after researching php.net.

**From php.net:**    mysqli_stmt::bind_result -- mysqli_stmt_bind_result — Binds variables to a prepared statement for result storage and binds columns in the result set to variables.

**My uncertainty:**
"binds columns" - What columns? Is PHP placing the variables (var1, var2, etc...) into columns. Does columns refer to columns in the database? In the meantime I'll research columns as it relates to myqli bind_result().

**From php.net:**
When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ....

**My uncertainty:**
"data into the specified variables var1" - What data? Is this data that the user is supplying? Is this data that bind_result($x) has generate and returned (magically?)

I have also tried to get an understanding of this function via a Stackoverflow post from a member with a similar problem - (Use bind_result to push into array) asked Jun 17 at 20:36 jskidd3 - Although his code example was quite similar to mine, his question(s) were not as basic as the question I have here.

I'm trying to get an in-depth understanding of mysqli "bind_result()" function and I don't have a clue of what's even happing at the surface. So, what is the purpose of this function? Also, can you theoretically illustrate what the prepare statement would look like after the binding result? And if possible can you clear up the ambiguity that I was left with from the PHP.net site? You can use the example below that I got from http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/2011/11/17/mysqli-cheatsheet/.

In my example below, I don't understand what value, of $filmName is being passed to the bind_result($filmName), and I don't understand what the result would be via the echo output?

I really appreciate your help and helping me understand what's going on with this function. Thank you!!

**Querying scenarios - One row from user input using prepare:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT filmID, filmName FROM movies WHERE filmID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['filmID']);
$stmt->execute(); 

//what value is being passed - and where is $filmName(and it's value) coming from?
$stmt->bind_result($filmName); 
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

//resulting value or output displayed? 
echo $filmName;
```

Comment: Why not to just *run* the above code and see?

Comment: @Nirk If I am allowed to give a recommendation too - if you want to answer on some technology, try to use it first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "binds columns"

refers to columns of the result of the query.

> "data into the specified variables var1"

When you perform a fetch (like `$stmt->fetch()`) the bound variables are assigned values based on the binding.  You don't need to explicitly assign the values each time.

For your query

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT filmID, filmName FROM movies WHERE filmID = ?");
```

The columns are, in order, `filmID`, `filmName`.

When you call `bind_result`, it binds the first variable to the first column in the result.  In this case,

```
$stmt->bind_result($filmName);
```

actually ends up binding the variable `$fileName` to the `filmID` field.

If you want the filmName to be bound properly, you can either rework the query so that filmName is first:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT filmName, filmID FROM movies WHERE filmID = ?");
```

OR you can bind the filmID variable:

```
$stmt->bind_result($filmID, $filmName);
```

Comment: Thank you Nirk for clearing this up for me. So, the example that was posted "mustbebuilt" was a bad example. First, you don't need to select the "filmID" since it is covered in the WHERE statement of query.

Comment: So, if index value of 3 was bound to the "?" via the bind_params function and the database "filmID" field/column with the record/row corresponding to the (3)index that happened to have the filmName value of "Gone with the Wind", then variable "$filmName", which we assigned to the database column labelled "filmName" through the use of bind_result($filmName) will have the value of "Gone with the Wind". Nirk, you made me so very happy! Thank you so much!! Sincerely, mmtalon.

Comment: My bad Nirk. This is my first post and I didn't know I was supposed to click the check-mark. I got it done now. Thank again!

Comment: Oh, by-the way, I found your answer very useful; it has helped me tremendously. I hope my question and your answer will help others understand this function as much as it has helped me.

Comment: But be aware that in MySQL/Mariadb a boolean value is stored as a tiny integer so when fetching it, the variable will also be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the following statement in PHP the results are stored in MySQL, not in PHP. The way the binary MySQL protocol works is that you need to fetch each row from the statement until MySQL tells you there is nothing more to be fetched.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT filmID, filmName FROM movies WHERE filmID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['filmID']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The designers of mysqli extension decided it would be a good idea (it's not) if instead of fetching a PHP array, each time you call `fetch()` method, the data from MySQL server will be bound into separate variables. The variables need to be bound using `bind_result()` method. The method will create the variables and each time the `fetch()` call is made it will assign the data coming from MySQL to the PHP variables. If the data is stored in PHP, then the data will be fetched from the internal buffer.

The columns refer to the list of columns you specified in your `SELECT` statement. The variables are bound in the same sequence that the columns were listed out in SQL. You are selecting two columns `filmID, filmName` so ideally you should provide two variables for PHP to insert the data into.

```
$stmt->bind_result($filmID, $filmName);
```